# What's the best way to `lazy load` images while needing to know their height and width?

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading

I'm trying to 'lazy load' dynamic images. Their height/width ratio matters in the layout of the webpage. I have four options to prevent them from messing up the DOM when they load or render.

1. I can get the height and width of the image using Javascript, set an element in the DOM to place-hold for the image until I want to load it later. I would use...

   `var image = new Image();
   var width = image.width; 
   var height = image.height;`
2. I can simply not lazy load them and use an `img` tag with a `src` immediately. If #1 is just as slow as this method then there's no point even trying to load them later and I may as well do it in an HTML tag.

   `<img src='source' />`
3. I can store the image dimensions in my database. This would mean I would continuously have the necessary dimensions of the image and could pretty easily set a placeholder. I don't know if this is common practice though. *Edit: it should be noted, I'm accessing the database to retrieve the image url anyways.*

   `<div>this elements width and height is set</div>`
4. I could get the dimensions of the image through PHP. This is the same as the Javascript method, just at a different point in the process.

   `$size = getimagesize($filename);`

My question is essentially which of the above is the most well established way of getting a pictures width and height to store a place for it in the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say a combination of method 2 and 3 are your best bets. You *should* store the image size and other metadata in your tables describing the image. You can then either do some form of dynamic loading, or just place a bunch of `<img>` tags, with `width` and `height` already set to the sizes from the DB and [`decoding=async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) so the browser doesn't block the rest of the page on loading these images.
The end state is to send a document to the browser, which contains the clear list of images you wish to display, and as much info about them as you can (sizes, loading modes, various srcs for various screen densities etc).

Method 1 seems like a lot of work, most of which would duplicate what the browser would already be doing.
Method 4 would be a performance nightmare. `getimagesize` would need to access the disk and read some part of each image you're trying to display. If there's a set of well known images, you'd be saved by disk caches, but otherwise, if you're doing something like instagram/facebook/flickr where every user has their own images you'd be looking at `O(n)` random disk reads atop whatever I/O the database does.

Comment: I think that's what I was leaning towards. I see a lot of advantages to storing all my image references in their own table with meta-data. I did notice a huge performance decrease when I used the PHP method so I'm glad you pointed out why that is. Thank you for your help. You pushed me in the right direction.